# magento 2.3.3 customer loggin issue quote table is_active?

Tags: magento2, customer, magento-enterprise, login

Magento 2.3.3 customer login issue quote table is_active?

When there is more than 1 data in the quote table with is_active = 1 then the user is facing login issues.

So I have to change is_active to 0 manually then the user is able to log in.

anyone? I am not able to get this behavior from Magento stuck in this.

Thanks

Comment: Not getting you please shed more light on it ( So that you get your answer )

Comment: @NileshDubey Yeah updated my Que.